# How to correctly use and serialize a JPA Entity in GWT

Tags: hibernate, gwt, serialization, jpa

How should I use JPA with Google Web Toolkit (GWT)? Also, what is the correct way to serialize an entity class, and use it at the client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An insightful discussion regarding this topic can be found within GWT's documentation pages: [Using GWT with Hibernate](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html). [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) is a popular implementation of [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API); similar ideas can be applied to other [JPA implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576659/jpa-implementations-which-one-is-the-best-to-use).

Comment: Thanks Darthenius. It helps a lot.