# Query regarding JPA, hibernate and EJB 3.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When we write java code we use JPA interfaces as its a java specification So we generally avoid using the third party implementation in Java code.

> Please verify this statement JPA is the specification, Hibernate and
>   EJB 3.0 is the implementation.

Please correct me if this is wrong and please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate implements the JPA specification entirely.  You do not need any part of the EJB 3.0 library.  I would say the correct statement is:

JPA is the specification, hibernate is the implementation.

Comment: There are several other libraries that implement JPA also. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576659/jpa-implementations-which-one-is-the-best-to-use

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Hibernate implements the JPA standard. EJB however is itself a standard.

I'm not an expert, either. The Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EJB), that EJB includes JPA as a requirement that an application server must implement to provide EJB. An application server can use Hibernate "under the hood" to implement JPA.