# Java MySQL API that populates results as per structure defined with a class

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've seen something to this effect in the past but I failed to find how I would do this so I will give pseudocode to demonstrate something I remember seeing this.

Table entries would be defined with a class, something to the following effect.

```
class Person {
    @ (an annotation that specified what SQL type to use for below field)
    String name;
    @ ...
    int age;
}
```

One would make SQL calls but the

```
Person[] persons = sqlconn.select("SELECT * FROM table_name", Person.class)
```

or something to this effect.

Not exactly prepare statements because these calls populate the objects.

Comment: i think you are looking for JPA and NativeQueries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity) will do this for you, but it has a fairly steep learning curve.

There are other JPA implementations to consider, some of which are explored [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576659/jpa-implementations-which-one-is-the-best-to-use).

A simple alternative is to use Spring's jdbcTemplate as detailed [here](http://www.wetfeetblog.com/spring-jdbc-template-leaner-alternative-fat-hibernate/328).