# java - map database tables into class

Tags: java, database, derby

When retrieving data from the database in Java, how can I get a instance of an class for each database row dynamically?

Example: 
I've got two tables (Table1: id, name, Table2: id, name, age) and two classes with the same properties. For every row in Table1 I want an List-item (or something related) for this row.

Is there a class/default method to do this in Java?

Comment: Use `Hibernate`. What you're looking for is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could implement your own mapper, [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) ([and the other JPA implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576659/521799)) will solve your problem quite thoroughly out of the box. If properly configured, loading records from `Table1` will automatically materialise your [`@OneToMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) relationship with `Table2`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Hibernate` or study [droidpersistence](https://code.google.com/p/droidpersistence/) library's source, (the lib is written for android though)

Answer (score 0):

Use [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html). A popular implementation of JPA is [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/). There are plenty of tutorials to get you started.